# Recommender system - multiple ratings by same user

Tags: r

In my data set, same users have rated same item, multiple times(although different ratings). As a result, [getRatings](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/recommenderlab.pdf) command is aggregating the ratings.

How can I tackle this problem while making a recommendation system?

```
library(recommenderlab)

 beer_beerid  review_profilename   review_overall
    5441            Kadonny            3.0
    5441            Kadonny            4.5
    5441            Kadonny            4.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `duplicated` and just use the columns you want to check. So ignore the `review_overall` column for this test...

```
duplicated_ratings <- duplicated(my_rating_df[c('beer_beerid','review_profilename')])
single_rating <- my_rating_df[!duplicated_ratings,]
```

In case you want to create an average, I would recommend `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
my_rating_df %>%
  group_by(beer_beerid, review_profilename) %>%
  summarise(average_rating=mean(review_overall)
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't it affect the overall recommendation as it removes the duplicate values and only keeps 1 value. Will making a recommendation be then trustworthy?

Comment: I am looking something of the sort: 5441  Kadonny  3.83(mean)

Comment: I edited my answer so I guess this should help to solve the problem.